# how to set self.rows.colnames as headers by capitalizing and trimming them for export_to_csv?

Tags: python, csv, header, web2py, export-to-csv

I can get column names from self.rows.colnames But it contains tablename.attributename format.
 for e.g: tblname.fieldname

Web2Py's export_to_csv uses it by default.

also db.tblname.fields will give you a list of column names.

I am getting internal errors whenever I tried to override the colnames using colnames parameter of export_to_csv
I want to set self.rows.colnames by trim and capitalize them and set them as a header for that csv.
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the parameter colnames, because, as the docs states: `colnames: list of column names to use (default self.colnames)`. And it's only purpose is to make you able to export only a subset of colnames, not something that isn't already on `self.colnames`. If you intend to simply have a different header on your csv you could:

1. Reopen the generated csv file and write your own header over the first line, or
2. Write your own csv serializer for your particular case of Rows object.

If you go with the second option, which i recommend, you should read the [csv.DictWriter documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects).